# what does "offset from the surrounding content" mean?

Tags: html, css

I was reading a html book which says:

**The b element is very simple: content contained between the start and end tags is offset from the surrounding content.**

so what does "offset from" mean? isn't that b element just put containing text in bold?

Comment: This is a question more suitable to an [**English Language**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) site on SO. The definition of "offset" can be found in any disctionary.

Answer (score 0):

In w3 docs you can read:

> The b element represents a span of text to be stylistically offset from the normal prose without conveying any extra importance, such as key words in a document abstract, product names in a review, or other spans of text whose typical typographic presentation is boldened.

Source: https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#the-b-element

Regards

Comment: so what does "stylistically offset from" mean?

Comment: @amjad That its *style* is *different from* [something else].

Answer (score 0):

The word "offset" may technically be a bit misapplied in this usage, but it's supposed to mean that the <b>oldened text *appears visually distinct or highlighted* from its surroundings.

Comment: Yeah, "set apart" would have been clearer than "offset" in this case.